# Databricks CROSS JOIN failing to identify column

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Whenever I apply a CROSS JOIN to my Databricks SQL query I get a message letting me know that a column does not exists, but I'm not sure if the issue is with CROSS JOIN

For example, code should identify characters such as http, https, ://, / and remove those characters and add a column called websiteurl without the characters aforemention. i.e.

[image]

The code is a follows:

```
SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        ,websiteurl = LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',v1.RightString)-1,-1),150))
   FROM basecrmcbreport.organizations tt
  CROSS join (VALUES(SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)))v1(RightString)
```

However, the above returns the following:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Column 'homepage_url' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? []; line 4 pos 31;
'Project ['tt.homepage_url, unresolvedalias(('websiteurl = 'LEFT('v1.RightString, 'COALESCE('NULLIF(('CHARINDEX(/, 'v1.RightString) - 1), -1), 150))), None)]
+- 'Join Cross
   :- SubqueryAlias tt
   :  +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.basecrmcbreport.organizations
   :     +- Relation basecrmcbreport.organizations[uuid#2439,name#2440,type#2441,permalink#2442,cb_url#2443,rank#2444,created_at#2445,updated_at#2446,legal_name#2447,roles#2448,domain#2449,homepage_url#2450,country_code#2451,state_code#2452,region#2453,city#2454,address#2455,postal_code#2456,status#2457,short_description#2458,category_list#2459,category_groups_list#2460,num_funding_rounds#2461,total_funding_usd#2462,... 22 more fields] parquet
   +- 'SubqueryAlias v1
      +- 'UnresolvedSubqueryColumnAliases [RightString]
         +- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1], [['SUBSTRING('homepage_url, ('CHARINDEX(//, 'homepage_url) + 2), 150)]]
```

Can someone let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Joins in general are used on tables but not table valued functions as `cross apply or outer apply`.

- The following is the sample data that I have used for demonstration.

[image]

- When I used the same query as yours, I got the same error.

```
%sql

SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        ,websiteurl = LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',v1.RightString)-1,-1),150))
   FROM demo tt
  CROSS join (VALUES(SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)))v1(RightString)
```

[image]

- To resolve this, I have used the select statement to remove the `https:// or http://` similar to your logic. Looking at the desired result, I have used inner join (instead of cross join) using `like` operator for defining condition. The query is as following

```
%sql

SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        , LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',v1.RightString)-1,-1),150)) as website_url
   FROM demo tt
  inner join (select (SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)) from demo)v1(RightString) where tt.homepage_url  like concat('%',v1.RightString)
```

[image]

**UPDATE for url with `\`:**

```
SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        , LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',replace(v1.RightString,'\\','/'))-1,-1),150)) as website_url
   FROM demo tt
  inner join (select (SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)) from demo)v1(RightString) on tt.homepage_url  like concat('%',v1.RightString,'%') escape '|';
```

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for reaching out. I tried your suggestion, but this time with more data. It appears to be working, however, I'm getting the error:
```AnalysisException: the pattern '%www.leapsint.com\' is invalid, it is not allowed to end with the escape character```

Comment: Hey @Patterson I have updated the query. You can change the escape character to something that does not even occur in the URL's. However, as in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/o70dstc.png), the backslash still exists as it is not handled (query written only for `/`). This needs to be handled to get required result.

Comment: To handle the backslash, I have used replace function to replace \ with /. Since we are already removing `/`, the solution would work without any issue. This is an [output image](https://i.imgur.com/krXFkjJ.png) for reference

Comment: Hey Saideep, going to try this now. Thank you

Comment: Hey Saideep, its running without any errors, therefore I can assume its work fine. However, its been running now for over 30mins. Having said that, at least its working, so thank you once again buddy

Comment: Hey Saideep, the code finally completed. It was a success. Thank you

Comment: Oh, Saideep, I have just realised that in some places the website_url is missing www.

Comment: If there is `www.` in the `homepage_url`, then there would be `www.` in website_url as well (2 reference images , one in solution and one in comments). Can you please provide an example homepage_url for which `www.` is missing ing website_url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248818/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).

Comment: Hey @Patterson, have you tried using `parse_url` as specified in the discussion chat? Please provide additional details if it is not working for your requirement.