# Databricks Concatenation Issue

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

As community member called Saideep help with an coding issue I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070117/databricks-cross-join-failing-to-identify-column/74071296#74071296)

I have attempted to modify the code to search for values with without www (after removing either http or https) and prepending it to a field value.

So, at the moment, my code does the following:
[image]

You can see from the image, that code successfully removes https:// and http, but it fails to prepend the values with www in the field newwebsite_url when doesn't exists in the homepage_url field

For example movingahead.com should appear as [www.movingahead.com](http://www.movingahead.com) in newwebsite_url

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        ,concat(iff(left(v1.RightString, 4)='www.', null, 'www.')) as addwww , LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',v1.RightString)-1,-1),150)) as newwebsite_url
   FROM basecrmcbreport.organizations tt
  inner join (select (SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)) from basecrmcbreport.organizations)v1(RightString) on tt.homepage_url  like concat('%',v1.RightString,'%') escape '|';
```

I know its a concatenation issue, but not where to fix it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the issue here is with concatenation. When using `concat` in the query, we have just given the part where taking `www.` if it is absent and null if it is present.

- But we are not concatenating this with the extracted part from URL (instead using it to create new column). To fix this, we have to place the above function value inside concat.
- The following is the demonstration of the same using my sample data.

[image]

- Using the following updated query, I was able to achieve your requirement.

```
%sql

SELECT  tt.homepage_url
        ,concat(iff(left(v1.RightString, 4)='www.', '', 'www.'),LEFT(v1.RightString,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',replace(v1.RightString,'\\','/'))-1,-1),150)))  as newwebsite_url
   FROM demo tt
  inner join (select (SUBSTRING(homepage_url,CHARINDEX('//',homepage_url)+2,150)) from demo)v1(RightString) on tt.homepage_url  like concat('%',v1.RightString,'%') escape '|';
```

[image]

**NOTE:** I have also replaced `\` with `/`. Also, I have used `''` (empty string) instead of using `null` in concat.

Comment: Perfect. Once again, thanks Saideep

Comment: Hi Saideep, I have just incorporated your into our production code, howeveer I'm getting the following error:
```nalysisException: the pattern '%inforgen.com/#tabNav|4%' is invalid, the escape character is not allowed to precede '4'``

Comment: I think there is a URL with value `inforgen.com/#tabNav|4`. Since we are giving escapse value as `|`, it is saying that it shouldn't be like that. I think changing the escapse character in the query from `|` to something unique should solve the issue. It should be a single character, so have to look for something that is not present in any of the URL's

Comment: Hi Saideep, once again you're spot on. I found the following in the dataset http://inforgen.com/#tabNav|4. So how would I accommodate for situations like this with your code?

Comment: I have checked and `parse_url` might not work for this specific requirement. Using ` (backtick) in escape character has worked for the above URL as well. This is [an image](https://i.imgur.com/mfjoOdc.png) for reference. However, if there is a URL with backtick in the URL, then the query would fail again. So, if we are using this way, then we have to use a unique escape value.